# Ormlite Image Update issue

Tags: java, android, orm, ormlite

I am using ormlite for android, I have following model

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = DatabaseConstants.TABLE_ARTICLE)
public class ArticleModel {

@DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = DatabaseConstants.ARTICLE_ID)
public int id;
@DatabaseField(columnName = DatabaseConstants.ARTICLE_NAME)
public String name = "";

@DatabaseField(columnName = DatabaseConstants.ARTICLE_IMAGE_URL)
public String imageUrl = "";

@DatabaseField(columnName = DatabaseConstants.ARTICLE_IMAGE,dataType= DataType.BYTE_ARRAY)
public byte[] image;
```

It is possible to update an image as follows:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(DatabaseConstants.ARTICLE_IMAGE, UtilBitmap.bitmapToByteArray(bitmap));

SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase =  this.baseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
sqLiteDatabase.update(DatabaseConstants.TABLE_ARTICLE, cv,           
DatabaseConstants.ARTICLE_MOBILE_IMAGE_URL + "= ?", new String[]{url});
```

But is there is an ormlite method to update to byte array other than the follwing code:

```
updateBuilder.updateColumnValue(DatabaseConstants.ARTICLE_IMAGE,imageBytes);
updateBuilder.where().eq(DatabaseConstants.ARTICLE_MOBILE_IMAGE_URL, url);
```

The problem is that it is possible to update the image using the former way but not using the latter way, ie, when using the latter way , image is not properly stored in database . I used the sqliteviewer to check whether image is stored , and it fails with the latter method. is there any better approach to update the byte array (image) using "ormlite"?

Comment: Was my answer some help?  I'd appreciate a +1 and an accept if so.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is using the [`SelectArg` feature](http://ormlite.com/docs/select-arg) of [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/).  You use `SelectArg` when you seen to specify a SQL `?` argument.  So you code would turn into:

```
updateBuilder.updateColumnValue(DatabaseConstants.ARTICLE_IMAGE,
    new SelectArg(imageBytes));
updateBuilder.where().eq(DatabaseConstants.ARTICLE_MOBILE_IMAGE_URL, url);
```

`SelectArg` also allows you to build your update statement and then set the argument multiple times before you execute the statement.  So if you are repeatedly updating a certain field, you don't have to build the same update statement multiple times.